# How can one best contribute Ubuntu even if you are no programmer?

Tags: ubuntu

Please some advice for a Ubuntu newbie? 
How can one best contribute to the further Development of Ubuntu even if you are no programmer?

Comment: This should be on [ubuntu.stackexchange.com](http://ubuntu.stackexchange.com).

Comment: When you go to an appropriate site for such a question please show them more respect than you've shown us and read their FAQ before posting.

Comment: John, what do you mean? The Question seems to be ok, when i see the answers the people gave. Where are you missing respect when such a question is asked?

Comment: @Dennis: I guess the question would have been better placed in askubuntu. Seems that i posted a bit to fast. Sorry for this guys, perhaps a mod is willing to move or migrate the question over there because the answers are really good and interesting.

Answer (score 4):

1. Translate Applications/Documentation.
2. Help in Technical Documentation.
3. Maintain Some Application (if you know source/version control and building applications)
4. Help in creating Graphics/Artwork.
5. Help in Marketing/trouble shooting non-technical bugs.
6. Provide Bandwidth/Space for hosting ubuntu images/apps.

Or Just Donate Money if cant do anything above. :)

Comment: +1 for documentation.  Setting up a blog and posting how to documents for event the 'simplest' of activities using screen shots and small words would also go a long way.  Remember, just as there are those more technical than you, there are also those less technical that find the (admittedly well written) documentation too technical to understand.

Answer (score 2):

You can contribute by helping others install it. Advocating. Testing new releases and filing bug reports. Donating. Trying to help people with problems.

All of the above stand for any project you want to contribute to, even if you do not write code for them.

Comment: +1 for filing bug reports. It's too easy to assume that someone else has already had your problem and reported it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Testing
2. Translation
3. Testing
4. Documentation
5. Testing

Everything always needs more testing and more time spent figuring out *exactly* how to cause bugs to happen - getting a bug reproducible is something like 80% toward getting it fixed.  You can even help with just the repro part for bugs that others report.

If you find a problem, follow up until you know it's been fixed appropriately.  Don't assume someone else has already reported it (though check for that, too).  Don't assume the developers have already fixed it, or that it will be fixed in the next release - make sure of it!